# Mintos.com login with python requests

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to write a tiny piece of software that logs into [mintos.com](https://www.mintos.com/en/login), and saves the account overview page (which is displayed after a successful login) in a html file. I tried some different approaches, and this is my current version.

```
import requests
import sys
import codecs

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach())

username = 'abc'
password = '123'

loginUrl = 'https://www.mintos.com/en/login'

resp = requests.get(loginUrl, auth=(username, password))
file = codecs.open("mint.html", "w", "UTF-8")
file.write(resp.text)
file.close()
```

When I run the code, I only save the original page, not the one I should get when logged in. I guess I'm messing up the login (I mean...there's not much else to mess up). I spent an embarrassing amount of time on this problem already.

Edit:
I also tried something along the lines of:

```
import requests
import sys
import codecs

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach())

loginUrl = "https://www.mintos.com/en/login";
username = "abc"
password = "123"
payload = {"username": username, "password": password}


with requests.session() as s:
    resp = s.post(loginUrl, data = payload)
    file = codecs.open("mint.html", "w", "UTF-8")
    file.write(resp.text)
    file.close()
```

Edit 2: Another non working version, this time with _csrf_token

```
with requests.session() as s:
    resp = s.get(loginUrl)
    toFind = '_csrf_token" value="'
    splited = resp.text.split(toFind)[1]
    _csrf_token = splited.split('"',1)[0]
    payload = {"_username": _username, "_password": _password, "_csrf_token": _csrf_token}

    final = s.post(loginUrl, data = payload)
    file = codecs.open("mint.html", "w", "UTF-8")
    file.write(final.text)
    file.close()
```

But I still get the same result. The downloaded page has the same token as the one I extract, though.

Final Edit: I made it work, and I feel stupid now. I needed to use "'https://www.mintos.com/en/login/check' as my loginUrl.

Answer (score 2):

The `auth` parameter is just a shorthand for `HTTPBasicAuth`, which is not what most websites use. Most of them use cookies or session data in order to store your login / info on your computer so they can check who you are while you're browsing the pages.

If you want to be able to log in on the website, you'll have to make a POST request on the login form and then store (and give back every time) the cookies they'll send to you. Also, this implies they don't have any kind of "anti-bot filter" (which makes you unable to login without having a real browser or, at least, not that easily).

Comment: Didn't realize that about auth, good to know. I've alredy tried something along the lines of this:import requests
import sys
import codecs

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach())

loginUrl = "https://www.mintos.com/en/login";
username = "abc"
password = "123"
payload = {"username": username, "password": password}


with requests.session() as s:
 resp = s.post(loginUrl, data = payload)
 file = codecs.open("mint.html", "w", "UTF-8")
 file.write(resp.text)
 file.close()  But that didn't work either.

Comment: I've updated my OP to add a version with POST I tried.

Comment: That can't work. Don't take it as reproach but do you know how HTML forms work? The one on mintos.com has fields `_username` and `_password` and you're giving them values for `username` and `password`...

Comment: I tried that too. "payload = {"_username": username, "_password": password}" or, for the sake of conformity, "payload = {"_username": _username, "_password": _password}" changes nothing in the outcome for me.

Comment: Well I just verified and in the form you have a field named `_csrf_token`, which you should also give. Though I'm not quite sure about how the server's handling that (you probably can't spoof that one).

Comment: Oh, you're right. I didn't realize that. Maybe I could fetch the page, get the token, and post it with the token. If that's happening in the same session it could work, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, csrf token is a little smarter than that fortunately... Don't think there's a way to override that.